# REST API CALLS to get journey builder running status

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I want to get running status of the journeys in a DE by using this URL

> https://{{et_subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/eventDefinitions

with journey id
Does anyone know what API call I have to use?

Answer (score 0):

For using Rest API you can use this URI to get the journey status

```
Host: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
GET /interaction/v1/interactions?id={{Journey_ID}}
Content-Type: application/json
```

It will return a response where the "status" property is the corresponding status for the **current** journey

E.g. Status equals "Published" mean "Running"

Or an alternative way is that you can use SQL query with `_Journey` MC data view to get the journey status

```SQL
SELECT
    , journey.JourneyName
    , journey.VersionNumber
    , journey.JourneyStatus
FROM _Journey AS journey
WHERE journey.JourneyID = 'Your journey ID'
```